# How can I apply reduction rates to a capital and estimate future capital values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10 companies with a capital that gets eroded over time or does not get eroded at all. The erosion rate may vary according to the time period, e.g. for the first case the erosion rate before 2030 (included) is -2% and after that is -5% until 2050.

I want to create additional columns with the calculation of the future capital values until 2050 discounting it for the different rates - how can I achieve this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
# Define target scopes
erossion1 = [
    (-0.02, 2030),
    (-0.05, 2050)
]

erossion2 = [
    (-0.02, 2050)
]
    
erossion3 = np.nan
    
# Define a simple DataFrame
data = {
    'Decrease Rate': [erossion1 for _ in range(5)] + [erossion2 for _ in range(3)] + [np.nan] + [np.nan] ,
    'Capital 2021': np.random.rand(10)*1000
}
    
test = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(test)
```

Comment: Instead of using `np.nan` i would suggest using `[(0, 2050)]` to make calculations easier. Also, please provide the desired output, as it is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "erosion"? What is the expected output? And what is the actual problem?

Comment: Decrease in capital!

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach to the question is to use scenarios. We can model it like this:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Erosion = namedtuple('Erosion', 'rate year')

scenarios = {
    'scenario1': [
        Erosion(-0.02, 2030),
        Erosion(-0.05, 2050)
    ],
    'scenario2': [
        Erosion(-0.02, 2050)
    ],
    'scenario3': [
        Erosion(0, 2050)
    ]
}

INITIAL_YEAR = 2021
FINAL_YEAR = 2050

for name, seq in scenarios.items():
    scenarios[name] = sorted(seq, key=lambda erosion: erosion.year)

for n, s in scenarios.items():
    assert s[0].year > INITIAL_YEAR, f'{n} should start at least from {INITIAL_YEAR + 1}'
    assert s[-1].year == FINAL_YEAR, f'{n} should end in {FINAL_YEAR}'
```

So the dummy data can be presented this way:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng; rng = default_rng(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Decrease Rate': pd.Categorical(['scenario1']*5 + ['scenario2']*3 + ['scenario3']*2),
        'Capital 2021': 1e3 * rng.random(10)
    }
)
```

Next, let's clarify what is *erosion*. From what I can guess, *erosion* means *decrease the current capital by the given rate each year until the final one reached*. So the formula for recalculation of the initial capital can be like this:

```py
def recalculate(capital, scenario, initial_year):
    '''scenario : list of Erosions'''
    prev = initial_year
    for rate, year in scenario:
        capital = capital * (1+rate)**(year-prev)
        prev = year
    return capital
```

Finally, we apply the formula to the initial capitals according to the given scenarios:

```py
df[f'Erosed Capital by {FINAL_YEAR}'] = df.apply(
    lambda rec: recalculate(rec['Capital 2021'], scenarios[rec['Decrease Rate']], INITIAL_YEAR),
    axis='columns'
)
```

Comment: Thanks will test and revert back